# I try to generate a big number with primal numbers 2 3 5 7 and 11 and then I try to factorize it and it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to generate a big number with primal numbers 2 3 5 7 and 11 and then I try to factorize it and it doesn't work. The problem is it doesn't factorize it completely. here's the code: (all the print() are for checking hoe the program goes)

```
 y = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
        print((2**y))
        z = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
        print(z)
        c = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
        print(c)
        v = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
        print(v)
        j = int(random.randrange(0, 20))
        print(j)
        e = int(((2**y)*(3**z)*(5**c)*(7**v)*(11**j)))
    for n in range (0, 200):
            if (e % 2) == 0:
                x = int(e / 2)
                print(x)
            elif (x % 3) == 0:
                x = int(x / 3)
                print(x)
            elif (x % 5) == 0:
                x = int(x / 5)
                print(x)
            elif (x % 7) == 0:
                x = int(x / 7)
                print(x)
            elif (x % 11) == 0:
                x = int(x / 11)
                print(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You never change the number you're factoring: you start with the original number each time.  To fix this, when you do the division, simply assign the result to the original:

```
if (e % 2) == 0:
    e = int(e/2)
```

Or, more simply,

```
    e //= 2    # Integer division, attached to the equals sign.
```

Note that you now have to change all of your **x** references to **e**:

```
elif (e % 3) == 0:
     e //= 3
     print e
```